# jboss/business-central-workbench-showcase docker image problem

Tags: jboss, drools, kie, kie-workbench, kie-wb

I use business-central-workbench-showcase 7.43.0 docker image, when I create a project(for example one of the sample projects of business central), it sticks in indexing. and when I press deploy button it sticks in building phase.I add two images of these problems.
[image: indexing when add new project]
[image: building when press deploy button]

I use this guide:
https://groups.google.com/g/drools-usage/c/EYftCpdEETA/m/lYKpeEZRBQAJ

to config heap size and run the docker with this instruction:

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8001:8001 -e JAVA_OPTS='-Xms4G -Xmx16G -XX:MetaspaceSize=4G -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=16G -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' -d --name jbpm-workbench jboss/business-central-workbench-showcase:latest
```

but it doesn't work.
Is there any problem with docker images?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What are the errors it gives? What actually happens?

Comment: when I press deploy button it just show "building" message and doesn't do anything.
something like freezing.